# Determine terrain color based on slope and height with many types of terrain

Tags: 3d, glsl, terrain, terrain-rendering

I've got a specific problem. Take this as a challenge, if you will.

I have a 3D mesh representing a cliffy terrain. It's constructed from a simple height map.

The goal is to determine what type of terrain (in practice, what color) to use for any point on the map, given a **height** and a **slope** and a constant configuration. Both height and slope are between 0 and 1.

The configuration looks something like this:

```
const vec3 WATER_COLOR = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
const vec3 SAND_COLOR = vec3(0.76, 0.7, 0.3);
const vec3 GRASS_COLOR = vec3(0.208, 0.624, 0.004);
const vec3 CLIFF_COLOR = vec3(0.435, 0.384, 0.380);
const vec3 SNOW_COLOR = vec3(0.894, 0.953, 1.0);

const float WATER_MAX_HEIGHT = 0.1;
const float SAND_MAX_HEIGHT = 0.15;
const float GRASS_MAX_HEIGHT = 0.5;
const float SNOW_MIN_HEIGHT = 0.9;

const float SAND_MAX_SLOPE = 0.25;
const float GRASS_MAX_SLOPE = 0.50;
const float SNOW_MAX_SLOPE = 0.75;

const float BLEND_FACTOR = 0.1; // Or whatever
```

I then need a function that takes a height and a slope to produce a color:

```
vec3 terrain_color(float slope, float height) {
    // Somehow determine the terrain color
}
```

I've tried to visualize the kind of function I want like this:

[image: A color map with slope on the x axis and height on the y axis.]

Where the x-axis is slope and the y-axis is height. So close to water, the terrain should be sand, but only if the slope is below `SAND_MAX_SLOPE` and very high up it should be snow, as long as the slope is below `SNOW_MAX_SLOPE`. The terrain defaults to the cliff color if nothing else fits.

It's easy to just compare the height and slope with the configuration values, but I would like to blend the colors smoothly together, except for the water, resulting in something similar to this:

[image: Same picture as above except the colours (aside from the water) are blurred]

A higher `BLEND_FACTOR` should result in more blurring/blending.

Closest thing I've got so far is the following (inspired by [Sebastian Lague's similar shader](https://github.com/SebLague/Hydraulic-Erosion/blob/master/Assets/Shaders/Terrain2.shader)):

```
const float HEIGHT_FADE_POWER = 16.0;
vec3 terrain_color(float slope, float height) {
    if (height <= WATER_MAX_HEIGHT) {
        return WATER_COLOR;
    }

    float sand_grow_height_fraction = smoothstep(0.0, SAND_MAX_HEIGHT, height);
    float sand_blend_height = SAND_MAX_SLOPE * (1.0 - BLEND_FACTOR);
    float sand_weight = 1.0 - saturate((slope - sand_blend_height) / (SAND_MAX_SLOPE - sand_blend_height));
    sand_weight *= 1.0 - pow(sand_grow_height_fraction, HEIGHT_FADE_POWER);

    float grass_grow_height_fraction = smoothstep(SAND_MAX_HEIGHT, GRASS_MAX_HEIGHT, height);
    float grass_blend_height = GRASS_MAX_SLOPE * (1.0 - BLEND_FACTOR);
    float grass_weight = 1.0 - saturate((slope - grass_blend_height) / (GRASS_MAX_SLOPE - grass_blend_height));
    grass_weight *= 1.0 - pow(grass_grow_height_fraction, HEIGHT_FADE_POWER) - sand_weight;

    float cliff_weight = 1.0 - grass_weight - sand_weight;

    return sand_weight * SAND_COLOR + grass_weight * GRASS_COLOR + cliff_weight * CLIFF_COLOR;
}
```

Which produces the following when I map it on a plane:

[image: A mesh colored similarly to the above 2 images but missing snow and with wrong slope correction for sand.]

Which is not quite what I want and it's also missing snow.

I have considered simply using the above image as a texture but I would like a computational way to achieve the same thing. I can't really figure out how to do this while getting the blending right. Besides I may want to replace the colors with a texture eventually.

Bonus points for having a different blend factor for each terrain type.